# Do we have “am Mittag” like “am Morgen”?

Tags: adverb, time

In my book TestDaf kompakt, it states we don’t have *am Mittag* in German language.

[image: excerpt from the book]

Is it true?

Comment: Of course there is both *mittags* and *am Mittag*. What does the book say exactly?

Comment: Depending on the region it might be unusual. I've never heard or used _am Mittag_ in Austria. To me _Mittag_ is a rather precise point in time (namely, noon) so it can't be quite used like _Vormittag_ or _Nachmittag_.  My preposition of choice would be _zu Mittag_.

Comment: @chirlu I added a picture from the book.

Comment: @Ingmar The books says it teaches Hochdeutsch.

Comment: The book doesn't specifically mention "am Mittag" or "zu Mittag", but that doesn't mean that those collocations don't exist. Check out Duden if you need more examples: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mittags

Comment: @Ingmar in all of the exercises, they don't include "am Mittag" and they never mention it.

Comment: On a side note @OP: Who is *we*? Are you learning or are you German? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options given to you in your book are only some of many. Every region has preferred ways of saying one thing or another.

For example, I wouldn’t use *am Morgen*, *morgens* or anything else related to *Morgen* being the beginning of a day except in the phrase *guten Morgen*. Instead, I refer to the time before lunch as *Früh*: *in der Früh*, *frühs* (not as good as the other ones) or just *heute früh*. In the same way, I often mingle *abends* and *nachts* together to *auf die Nacht*.

The expression *am Mittag* — and also *zu Mittag* in some areas — **are** allowed and widely used, only maybe just not as widely as *am Morgen* or *am Abend*. Although I couldn’t quote that if my life depended on it.

Things are further convoluted by the fact that *Mittag* is a rather short timeframe; it lasts less than two hours, usually only one. Things are also convoluted by the fact that *Mittag* can also be the short form of *Mittagessen* — so maybe the book was trying to do you some good to avoid misinterpreting something?

Frankly, I have no clue why they left it out and all I have to say is that [chirlu nailed it](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/23315/15318):

> When some term is not listed in a limited learner’s vocabulary, you can’t conclude from that fact alone that it doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 4):

The expression *am Mittag* is correct and used in German, but it may be less important and less useful than the other expressions in that list from the book, because those refer to longer parts of the day.

When some term is not listed in a limited learner’s vocabulary, you can’t conclude from that fact alone that it doesn’t exist.